# Save SharedPrefrence varibale

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to save SharedPreferences var for a day and rest it at a specific time, let's say 3 pm

The thing is I'm not sure if I'm saving the SharedPreferences var properly, when I run the app in the emulator and I click on the widget I can see the picture changing and this is how I want it to work. But when I click back then I return to the same page the SharedPreferences var reset itself like it didn't save it at all.

Please let me know if I'm doing anything wrong, appreciate the help.

```
class Today extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TodayState createState() => _TodayState();
}

class _TodayState extends State<Today> {
  // Future<SharedPreferences> prefs1 = SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  // Future<int> pic;

  DateTime time = DateTime.now();
  Random random = new Random();


  int intValue3 = 0;

  int number3 = 0;




  getIntValue3() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs3 = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    //Return int
    setState(() {
      if (intValue3 == 0) {
      intValue3 = random.nextInt(4);
    }
    intValue3 = prefs3.getInt('intValue3');
    });
    
    return intValue3;
  }

    loadDate()async{

    SharedPreferences prefs3 = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    int number3 = random.nextInt(4);

    print('$number3 3');

    prefs3.setInt('intValue3', number3);
    
  }

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    
    loadDate();
  }

  @override


  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.black,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                child: FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pop(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                          return ScreenTwo();
                        }),
                      );
                    },
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.arrow_back_ios,
                      color: Colors.grey,
                      size: 50.0,
                    ))),

            Material(
              child: InkWell(
                child: Container(
                  height: 200,
                  width: 70,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      image: DecorationImage(
                          image: AssetImage("img/mg$intValue3.jpg"))),
                ),
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    getIntValue3();
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
            
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: is it really a difficult one?

Answer (score 0):

if u want to save to SharedPreference You have to save it like this
preference.setString('tagName', data);

Ex:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  preferences.setString('id', userId);
```

and when you can get it by :

```
print(preferences.getString('id'));
```

Comment: in your case you want to save int in preference just change from .setString('tag' ,data) to .setInt('tag' , data) like this

Comment: oh I didn't see that sorry your var reset to null or just change data in var ?

Comment: I tried to change the vars to var but nothing changed, when i get back to the page it is 0 again and nothing was saved!